# PHP Curl GET call troubleshooting

Tags: php, curl, get, xampp

I am building a website that makes standard HTTP calls to an API. My first call is a straight-forward GET with no parameters using basic auth. I am using Curl in my php. I am running this via a local install of XAMPP. My call is not working but if i have a colleague run the php on his Linux box running an older version of ubuntu PHP it works fine. What is the best way to troubleshoot this issue? My guess is it is something with my XAMPP install but is there a good method for troubleshooting? I have used curl_getinfo on my curl session to get the return values and it doesn't seem to provide much insight as far as I can tell.

Here is the curl_getinfo output:

```
Array ( 
[url] => https://www.ebusservices.net/webservices/hrpcertws/rbs/api/merchants/267811683882/consumers.xml? 
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0 
[header_size] => 0 
[request_size] => 107 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0.28 
[namelookup_time] => 0.015 
[connect_time] => 0.015 
[pretransfer_time] => 0 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => -1 
[upload_content_length] => -1 
[starttransfer_time] => 0 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
[primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1 
[primary_port] => 8888 
[local_ip] => 127.0.0.1 
[local_port] => 59509 
[redirect_url] => 
)
```

I am using:
XAMPP 1.8.1
PHP Version 5.4.7
cURL 7.24.0
on Windows 7

Added Code:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $session = 'FALSE';
    // Initialize the session
    $session = curl_init();

    $stderr = fopen("curl.txt", "w+"); 

    // Set curl options
    curl_setopt($session,     CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.ebusservices.net/webservices/hrpcertws/rbs/api/merchants/12233442/consumers.xml?');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_STDERR, $stderr);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:pwd");
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Make the request
    $response = curl_exec($session);

    print_r(curl_getinfo($session));

    // Close the curl session
    curl_close($session);

    fclose($stderr);

    // Get HTTP Status code from the response
    $status_code = array();
    preg_match('/\d\d\d/', $response, $status_code);

    // Check the HTTP Status code
    if(isset($status_code[0]))
    {
         switch( $status_code[0] ) 
    {
            case 100:
                   break;
            case 200:
                   break;
            case 503:
                   die('Your call to HRP API failed and returned an HTTP status of 503. That means: Service unavailable. An internal problem prevented us from returning data to you.');
                   break;
            case 403:
                   die('Your call to HRP API failed and returned an HTTP status of   403. That means: Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this resource, or are over your rate limit.');
                   break;
            case 400:
                  die('Your call to HRP API failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means:  Bad request. The parameters passed to the service did not match as expected. The exact error is returned in the XML response.');
                  break;
            case 401:
                  die('Your call to HRP API failed and returned an HTTP status of 401. That means: Unauthorized. The credentials supplied do not have permission to access this resource.');
                  break;
            case 404:
                  die('Page not found.');
                  break;
            default:
                  die('Your call to HRP API returned an unexpected HTTP status of:' . $status_code[0]);
        } 
    }
    else
    { 
       echo 'failed';
    }

     // Get the XML from the response, bypassing the header
    if (!($xml = strstr($response, '<?xml'))) {
        $xml = null;
        //echo 'in xml';
    }

     // Output the XML
     echo htmlspecialchars($xml, ENT_QUOTES);

?>
```

Comment: Add the verbose option and see what the output is one the command line. And you should show some code.

Comment: Have the receiving page do a `php_info()` and check the returned info.

Comment: I can run the GET from a curl command line outside of XAMPP and it works fine. Is there a way to run the curl command line using the same curl within xampp? I was not aware that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see exactly what is in the HTTP traffic.

Comment: I tried using Fiddler but the only entry i get is the initial "CONNECT" to the base url "www.ebusservices.net:443". I get no other entries. Its TextView states the clienthello handshake was found and I see some entries within the ciphers that state "unrecognized cipher". Does this point to a possible certificate issue? I wouldn't think so since I can successfully process this GET via the cURL command line and SoapUI.

Comment: I'd have to see the Fiddler output before I could really tell what is going on.